# Podio webhook IP address?

Tags: podio

Looking to whitelist the IP address for webhooks. I'm implementing some automations using the PHP SDK for a client, but their server isn't accessible via HTTP unless we whitelist the specific IP address of origin. Where do those posts originate from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As Podio is built on a scaleable infrastructure we continuously add more capacity to our background worker cluster. This means that we cannot guarantee which IP addresses we will connect *from* when doing a webhook.

Comment: Can we at least get a list of the IP address you currently use? This seems like a pretty basic request to ensure the security of our server.